# What is the source for the bracha "enwrap ourselves"?

Tags: blessing

Where are we commanded to enwarp ourselves in a tallis (לְהִתְעַטֵּף בַּצִּיצִית)?

Comment: Moed Katan 24,not so,simple though ,but it's a start

Comment: @sam. Where on the page, please.  I looked quickly and did not find it.

Comment: וכל עטיפה שאינה כעטיפת ישמעאלים אינה עטיפה